# What is the viewConfig equivalent in ExtJS version 3?

Tags: extjs

I've been searching for something that equivocates to viewConfig from version 4 in version 3, but I can't seem to find anything.

Specifically, I'm trying to achieve the same on right-click effect seen here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/menu/action-grid.html

Thanks

Comment: You should look in the API because it is [viewConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.PropertyGrid-cfg-viewConfig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is viewConfig! no changes :)

check out this link:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-cfg-viewConfig

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  At least now I know for sure.